# Best volume OSD for Lubuntu

Tags: sound, lubuntu, notification, volume-control, notify-osd

It's a few months I use lubuntu and I'm pretty happy with it, the problem for me is that it appears it doesn't have a pre-installed volume OSD.

What I'm looking for is a feedback pop-up volume bar that appears anytime I change volume on my PC up or down, just like a tv (https://cnet2.cbsistatic.com/img/gD5-W1LnD5DW4snNV8_hBLQoIus=/fit-in/x/2013/06/11/064a6bed-fdc7-11e2-8c7c-d4ae52e62bcc/banner_1.jpg) or the ugly but working Windows 10's one (http://thewindowsclub.thewindowsclubco.netdna-cdn.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/06/Hide-On-Screen-Volume-Indicator-in-Windows-10.jpg).

Looking through the web for a Lubuntu OSD I found mostly old threads and most solutions required the OSD to be launched everytime, but I'm looking for something or someway to make it run automatically on start up since most of the time when I don't use my PC for my job I use it as a TV so I'd like it to always work whenever I hit volume up or down.

To be more specific I'm looking for an indicator that tells me what level the volume is everytime I change it, I don't need anything heavy on system (I chose the Lubuntu distro specifically for my old grumpy laptop) or with lots of additional settings with mixers or anything, I just want a visual feedback of my volume level. If you have some screenshot of the volume OSD it will be appreciated.

It's strange that there is not much discussion about this on the web and so few and ugly choices; when the problem first presented itself I expected to find extensive charts of the best volume OSD for Linux since, as I understood, not all distros have it by design, this is an essential feature for me, I'm really wondering why Lubuntu has an OSD for brightness level and not for volume (https://cdn.pbrd.co/images/H6I0neq.png).

Thank you